# determine which IOS is running on the device

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad, twitter

I have in my app a facebook share button, a tweet button. My app supports to IOS 5.1. 
So for twitter there is no problem. But how should I work with the facebook share button.

If the IOS device that is running the app is using IOS6 I want to use the new way, like you can see over [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=facebook%20share%20in%20app%20ios&um=1&hl=nl&sa=N&tbm=isch&tbnid=IFGDxpn5cChLRM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.theiospost.com/latest/2012/9/19/ios-6-review.html&docid=pfXBWRkOxzy7nM&imgurl=http://www.theiospost.com/storage/iOS6-Review-FacebookShareSheet.png%253F__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION%253D1348056541859&w=765&h=1499&ei=_vF_ULfTLe7R4QS504HgBw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=299&sig=114756556720582691644&page=1&tbnh=156&tbnw=80&start=0&ndsp=27&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:20,i:144&tx=33&ty=78&biw=1422&bih=707)

But when the app is running on previous IOS devices. I want to use the old fashion way.

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Just use the new Facebook 3.0 iOS SDK, this will handle it all for you. Also the [Twitter framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) is deprecated in iOS 6, you should move to the [social framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233). And you should never build something that checks the iOS version, just check wether a class is available: `if ([SLRequest class] != nil)`

Comment: @rckoenes Okay, first I used the social framework for both facebook like and twitter tweet. But I understand you correctly I should use for facebook the Facebook 3.0 IOS SDK and for twitter the social framework. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, the Facebook SDK will use the native Social Framwork if available.

Comment: Because Apple provides a Social Framework use it instead of iOS version number. What if in the next version of iOS, Apple removes facebook? Then you have to modify your code again.

Comment: @rckoenes Out of curiousity, what if the class in question had been introduced privately?  Wouldn't that return a false positive?

Comment: @borrrden You might be right, not sure though. Apple has given some examples where they do the `class != nil` check so I guess that there problem then ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're wondering if `SLComposeViewController` supports Facebook, check [`isAvailableForServiceType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType:), e.g.

```
if ([SLComposeViewController class]) {
    // once you know that they have iOS 6 or higher
    // check if the account is setup
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        // now we know we have a facebook account configure and logged in
    }
} else {
    // You don't have iOS 6 or higher
}
```

It's generally better to use API (or `class` or `NSClassFromString` for weakly linked classes, or `respondsToSelector`, if a class has methods that were added in later versions of iOS) rather than checking for version of iOS. For more information, see [Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW4)  section of the *iOS App Programming Guide.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] == 6)
{
 // your code for iOS 6
}
else
{
 // your code for other iOS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:
First weak link the social framework (make it optional)

Next check to see if the app can you use SLComposeViewController and then check to see if the user has set up their Facebook account

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != nil)
{
  if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]])
  {
   //Add your SLComposeViewController code
  }
}
```